# How is my non-published blog getting so much spam?

Tags: spam

A few weeks ago I created a new WordPress blog. I bought a new domain name for it, and I have not published/linked to the blog yet (because I wanted to get a few articles up first, I only have 2 so far).

I have gotten about 10 spam comments already. I am confused how the spammers could be finding me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your privacy settings?

Go to **Dashboard -> Settings -> Privacy**

If it is set to *I would like my site to be visible to everyone, including search engines (like Google, Bing, Technorati) and archivers*, then your site is actively being crawled/indexed by search engines, and thus visible to spammers.

If it is set to *I would like to block search engines, but allow normal visitors*, and you're still getting spam comments, then that would be a bit more surprising. In that case, you might want to look at disabling comments, or looking at some anti-spam solutions.

Comment: Yes it was set to visible, I wanted search engines to be able to crawl my site, but I didn't realize they would already be before I told them about it.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the domain history?.. it could well be an expired domain with the URI in the hands of spammers

Comment: Good suggestion thanks, do you know how to look at the history?

Comment: check it via using whois domain tools and look for a previous history